# Opencover execute test cases on Category base

Tags: c#, opencover

I need to execute test case dll using open-cover.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Apps\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe "-target:C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" "-targetargs:C:\TravelInsurance\BTS\src\Fortius.Services.TravelGuard.Tests\bin\Debug\WorldVentures.Fortius.Services.TravelGuard.Tests.dll" -register:Administrator
```

My test case has a condition to execute

```
--where "cat == Unit"
```

How should I add this condition so that it can add only category "Unit" This question is an duplication of `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42691814/unexpected-token-at-position-3-in-selection-expression?noredirect=1#comment72547670_42691814`

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Apps\OpenCover\OpenCover.Console.exe "-target:C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit.org\nunit-console\nunit3-console.exe" "-targetargs:C:\TravelInsurance\BTS\src\Fortius.Services.TravelGuard.Tests\bin\Debug\WorldVentures.Fortius.Services.TravelGuard.Tests.dll --where cat==Unit " -register:Administrator
```